# behavior of pipe operator in compostie functions purrr - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, purrr

usage of pipe operator in purrr-dplyr packages is (in short) defined as follows:

> y%>%f(x,.,z) is the same as f(x,y,z)

I am trying to do the following task using pipe operator. First I show you the task without using pipes:

```
#####for reproducibility
set.seed(50)
z0<-factor(sample(c(letters[1:3],NA),100,replace = T))
###the task
rep(1,length(table(z0)))
```

now I want to do this using pipes:

```
z0%>%table%>%rep(1,length(.))
```

however the result is not the same. It seems that pipe operator cannot handle the proper assignation to a composition of functions. That is

> y%>%f(x,g(.)) should be the same as f(x,g(y))

so, the concrete question is if ti is possible to do

> y%>%f(x,g(.))

Thank you in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%>%` implements a first argument rule, that is, it passes the previous data as first argument to the function if `.` is not a direct argument; In your second case, the argument to `rep` is `1` and `length(.)`, so the first argument rule takes effect; To avoid this, use `{}` to enclose the expression; You can read more about this [at Re-using the placeholder for attributes](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr):

> **Re-using the placeholder for attributes**
>
> It is straight-forward to use the placeholder several times in a
>   right-hand side expression. **However, when the placeholder only appears
>   in a nested expressions magrittr will still apply the first-argument
>   rule.** The reason is that in most cases this results more clean code.
>
> ```
>  x %>% f(y = nrow(.), z = ncol(.)) is equivalent to f(x, y = nrow(x), z = ncol(x))
> ```
>
> The behavior can be overruled by enclosing the right-hand side in
>   braces:
>
> ```
> x %>% {f(y = nrow(.), z = ncol(.))} is equivalent to f(y = nrow(x), z = ncol(x))
> ```

```
rep(1,length(table(z0)))
# [1] 1 1 1
```

Equivalent would be:

```
z0 %>% table %>% {rep(1,length(.))}
# [1] 1 1 1
```